# Can't use rvm install rails 5 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, ruby-2.3

I tried to create gemset rails500 by ruby-2.3.1 and I got :

> ```
> Using /Users/ChamperWu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1 with gemset rails500
> jiaqideMacBook-Pro:unispot ChamperWu$ gem install rails
> Fetching: i18n-0.7.0.gem (100%)
> Successfully installed i18n-0.7.0
> Fetching: thread_safe-0.3.5.gem (100%)
> Successfully installed thread_safe-0.3.5
> Fetching: tzinfo-1.2.2.gem (100%)
> Successfully installed tzinfo-1.2.2
> Fetching: concurrent-ruby-1.0.2.gem (100%)
> Successfully installed concurrent-ruby-1.0.2
> Fetching: activesupport-5.0.0.1.gem (100%)
> Successfully installed activesupport-5.0.0.1
> Fetching: rack-2.0.1.gem (100%)
> Successfully installed rack-2.0.1
> Fetching: rack-test-0.6.3.gem (100%)
> Successfully installed rack-test-0.6.3
> Fetching: mini_portile2-2.1.0.gem (100%)
> Successfully installed mini_portile2-2.1.0
> Fetching: nokogiri-1.6.8.1.gem (100%)
> Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
> ERROR:  Error installing rails:
>   ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
>     current directory: /Users/ChamperWu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails500/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8.1/ext/nokogiri
> /Users/ChamperWu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20161026-41490-k9it32.rb extconf.rb
> checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
> checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
> Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
> Using mini_portile version 2.1.0
> checking for iconv.h... yes
> checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
> checking for iconv using --with-opt-* flags... yes
> ************************************************************************
> IMPORTANT NOTICE:
>
> Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.4.
>
> Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
> updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
> to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
> reinstall nokogiri as follows:
>
>     gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
>         [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
>         [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]
>
> If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:
>
>     bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
>     bundle install
>
> Note, however, that nokogiri is not fully compatible with arbitrary
> versions of libxml2 provided by OS/package vendors.
> ************************************************************************
> Extracting libxml2-2.9.4.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.4... OK
> Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.9.4... OK
> Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.9.4... ERROR, review '/Users/ChamperWu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails500/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8.1/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.4/compile.log'
> ```
>
> to see what happened. Last lines are:
>       ========================================================================
>           unsigned short* in = (unsigned short*) inb;
>                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       encoding.c:815:27: warning: cast from 'unsigned char *' to 'unsigned short *' increases required alignment from 1 to 2
>   [-Wcast-align]
>           unsigned short* out = (unsigned short*) outb;
>                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       4 warnings generated.
>         CC       error.lo
>         CC       parserInternals.lo
>         CC       parser.lo
>         CC       tree.lo
>         CC       hash.lo
>         CC       list.lo
>         CC       xmlIO.lo
>       xmlIO.c:1450:52: error: use of undeclared identifier 'LZMA_OK'
>           ret =  (__libxml2_xzclose((xzFile) context) == LZMA_OK ) ? 0 : -1;
>                                                          ^
>       1 error generated.
>       make[2]: *** [xmlIO.lo] Error 1
>       make[1]:**  [all-recursive] Error 1
>       make:  **[all] Error 2
>       ========================================================================
>       *** extconf.rb failed ***
>       Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
>       libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
>       need configuration options.
>
> ```
> Provided configuration options:
>   --with-opt-dir
>   --with-opt-include
>   --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>   --with-opt-lib
>   --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>   --with-make-prog
>   --without-make-prog
>   --srcdir=.
>   --curdir
>   --ruby=/Users/ChamperWu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
>   --help
>   --clean
>   --use-system-libraries
>   --enable-static
>   --disable-static
>   --with-zlib-dir
>   --without-zlib-dir
>   --with-zlib-include
>   --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
>   --with-zlib-lib
>   --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
>   --enable-cross-build
>   --disable-cross-build
> /Users/ChamperWu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails500/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:366:in
> ```
>
> `block in execute': Failed to complete compile task (RuntimeError)
>         from /Users/ChamperWu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails500/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:337:in`
>   chdir'
>         from /Users/ChamperWu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails500/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:337:in
>   `execute'
>         from /Users/ChamperWu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails500/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:111:in`
>   compile'
>         from /Users/ChamperWu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails500/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:150:in
>   `cook'
>         from extconf.rb:365:in`block (2 levels) in process_recipe'
>         from extconf.rb:258:in `block in chdir_for_build'
>         from extconf.rb:257:in`chdir'
>         from extconf.rb:257:in `chdir_for_build'
>         from extconf.rb:364:in`block in process_recipe'
>         from extconf.rb:263:in `tap'
>         from extconf.rb:263:in`process_recipe'
>         from extconf.rb:556:in `'
>
> ```
> To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:
>
>   /Users/ChamperWu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails500/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.3.0/nokogiri-1.6.8.1/mkmf.log
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in /Users/ChamperWu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails500/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8.1
> ```
>
> for inspection.
>       Results logged to /Users/ChamperWu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails500/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.3.0/nokogiri-1.6.8.1/gem_make.out

I tried to uninstall and install it again, but I got the same info

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might help:

`brew uninstall xz`

`gem install nokogiri -v 1.6.8` or `gem install rails` (command you are running)

Comment: I install rails successfully! thx a lot
Can you tell me what about xz?

Comment: xz installs a version of liblzma which can not be linked against when building nokogiri dependencies. Uninstalling allows the libxml compile to succeed